# Fixed clock generator with generic parameter called num_cycles

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I have to make it display as many pulses as the num_cycle variable. So if it is set to 3, there will be 3 clock pulses. I have gotten this far:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity fixed_clock is
    generic ( num_cycles : integer := 1); --at least 1
    Port ( enable : in STD_LOGIC;
           reset : in STD_LOGIC;
           clk_out : inout STD_LOGIC);
end fixed_clock;

architecture Behavioral of fixed_clock is
begin
    process(enable, reset)
    begin
        if(reset='1') then
            clk_out<='0';
        elsif(enable='1') then
            for I in 1 to num_cycles*2 loop
                 clk_out<=not clk_out;
            end loop;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

I also wrote the test bench as so

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.Numeric_Std.all;

entity fixed_clock_tb is
end;

architecture bench of fixed_clock_tb is

  component fixed_clock
      generic ( num_cycles : integer := 1);
      Port ( enable : in STD_LOGIC;
             reset : in STD_LOGIC;
             clk : inout STD_LOGIC);
  end component;

  signal enable: STD_LOGIC;
  signal reset: STD_LOGIC;
  signal clk: STD_LOGIC;
  signal num_cycles: INTEGER;
begin

  -- Insert values for generic parameters !!
  uut: fixed_clock generic map ( num_cycles =>  num_cycles)
                      port map ( enable     => enable,
                                 reset      => reset,
                                 clk        => clk );

  stimulus: process
  begin

    num_cycles:=3;
    enable<=0;
    reset<='1';
    wait for 10 ns;
    reset<='0';
    enable<='1';
    wait for 50 ns;

    wait;
  end process;
end;
```

I keep getting an error. What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This isn't a code-writing service. Please have a go yourself and, if some specific question about VHDL results, there are many people here who would be very happy to answer it.

Comment: Your question isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), lacking a description of 'an error'.

Comment: What you should do is read the error message, understand what it means, and modify the code so that it no longer has that error. If you don't understand the error message, add it to the question and ask for help explaining it.

Comment: num_cycles is a signal, so you must use signal assignment statements (not variable assignment): `num_cycles <= 3;`

Comment: Besides, if you have an integer generic that must always be greater or equal than 1 you should use `positive` as type.